# dhclient cloud-init /var/tmp process

Tags: network, linux, ubuntu, dhcp

There's a process that's running that I'm trying to investigate why its running and what its doing. The server is a Linux Ubuntu server running on AWS. Running 16.04.

The process in question is:

```
root 829 0.0 0.0 16116 2888 ? Ss Jun19 0:04 /var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-zaislidv/dhclient -1 -v -
```

When I ran lsof -p 829:

```
sudo lsof -p 829
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
dhclient 829 root  cwd    DIR              259,1     4096       2 /
dhclient 829 root  rtd    DIR              259,1     4096       2 /
dhclient 829 root  txt    REG              259,1   487248 1536424 /var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-zaislidv/dhclient (deleted)
dhclient 829 root  mem    REG              259,1    47600    1993 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
dhclient 829 root  mem    REG              259,1    14608    1982 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
dhclient 829 root  mem    REG              259,1  1868984    1980 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
dhclient 829 root  DEL    REG              259,1             2123 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-export.so.160.0.0
dhclient 829 root  DEL    REG              259,1             2125 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdns-export.so.162.1.3
dhclient 829 root  mem    REG              259,1   162632    1978 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
dhclient 829 root    0u   CHR                1,3      0t0       6 /dev/null
dhclient 829 root    1u   CHR                1,3      0t0       6 /dev/null
dhclient 829 root    2u   CHR                1,3      0t0       6 /dev/null
dhclient 829 root    3u  unix 0xffff880036debc00      0t0   12925 type=DGRAM
dhclient 829 root    5u  pack              12942      0t0     ALL type=SOCK_RAW
dhclient 829 root    6u  IPv4              12943      0t0     UDP *:bootpc
```

Out of 200 servers this is the only one running this process.

I enter the /var/tmp/cloud-init dir and its empty of course and I don't see this executable even in there.

Any insight on what it is and where it may be configured to run at?

When I run systemctl status --no-pager cloud-init-local.service --full:

```
systemctl status --no-pager cloud-init-local.service --full
● cloud-init-local.service - Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cloud-init-local.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-06-19 15:31:39 UTC; 5 months 24 days ago
 Main PID: 859 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Tasks: 1
 Memory: 8.6M
 CPU: 10.408s
 CGroup: /system.slice/cloud-init-local.service
       └─829 /var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-zaislidv/dhclient -1 -v -lf /var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-zaislidv/dhcp.leases -pf /var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-zaislidv/dhclient.pid ens5 -sf /bin/true

Dec 12 20:37:38 hostname dhclient[829]: bound to IP -- renewal in 1599 seconds.
Dec 12 21:04:17 hostname dhclient[829]: DHCPREQUEST of IP on ens5 to 10.80.10.1 port 67 (xid=0x36c118d4)
Dec 12 21:04:17 hostname dhclient[829]: DHCPACK of IP from IP
Dec 12 21:04:17 hostname dhclient[829]: can't create /var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-zaislidv/dhcp.leases: No such file or directory
Dec 12 21:04:17 hostname dhclient[829]: can't create /var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-zaislidv/dhcp.leases: No such file or directory
Dec 12 21:04:17 hostname dhclient[829]: bound to IP -- renewal in 1433 seconds.
Dec 12 21:28:10 hostname dhclient[829]: DHCPREQUEST of IP on ens5 to IP port 67 (xid=0x36c118d4)
Dec 12 21:28:10 hostname dhclient[829]: DHCPACK of IP from IP
Dec 12 21:28:10 hostname dhclient[829]: can't create /var/tmp/cloud-init/cloud-init-dhcp-zaislidv/dhcp.leases: No such file or directory
Dec 12 21:28:10 hostname dhclient[829]: bound to IP -- renewal in 1353 seconds.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

lsof shows that the executable has been deleted.

Looks like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+bug/1732964 shows a similar bug where the dhclient gets left running.

Might be worth checking:

```
systemctl status --no-pager cloud-init-local.service --full
```

And see if that reports the process?

---

Looks like you've hit the same bug, where a temporary copy of dhclient get's left running.
The bug report suggests they've fixed it - I'd suggest updating your server.

Comment: I added the output that I got to the post.